# Running a custom profile file on remote host

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a custom profile script on a remote host.
I'd like to source it when I connect to the host automatically.
I cannot change anything on the remote host.
Things I've tried but didn't work:

```
ssh -t myhost '. /local/scratch/scripts/rtc_profile ; bash -l'
ssh -t myhost 'bash -l /local/scratch/scripts/rtc_profile'
```

I've also tried the following (which works), but it skips all other rcfiles:

```
ssh -t myhost 'bash --rcfile /local/scratch/scripts/rtc_profile '
```

Please help :)

Comment: Why not just have your `rtc_profile` file source the normal `.bashrc` file at the end and use `--rcfile`?

Comment: Thought of this, but is .bashrc is the only rcfile by default?

Comment: From the man page: "--rcfile file - Execute commands from file instead of the standard personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive". What your bashrc file loads in addition to that is something else. Read the `INVOCATION` section of the bash man page for the full startup file details.

Comment: Well, ~/.bashrc apparently doesn't exist on the host. ~/.bash_profile does. So I can source that one, but I fear I might miss out on any other rc files.

Comment: `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are sourced for different types of shells. Read the `INVOCATION` section. It is somewhat complicated. Though the short version is if you don't have a `$HOME/.bashrc` file then `--rcfile` can't hurt you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following at the end of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ ! -z "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] ; then
    source /local/scratch/scripts/rtc_profile
fi
```

Comment: Like I said, I can't change the remote bashrc

Comment: Where did you said this? And **you can** change the `~/.bashrc` (as it is owned by user)

Comment: "I cannot change anything on the remote host"

Comment: What means you cannot change anything? Why?

Comment: I cannot edit files on the remote host. Only in the /local/scratch directory.

Comment: What gives you `echo $HOME` on the remote host?