# bash process started from C# returns unexpected characters

Tags: c#, bash, cygwin, io-redirection, mintty

I started bash (cygwin) from C# and I for that purpose created a new process from `C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe` with the arguments `--login -i`. I've also redirected its output.

Bash runs, but the output contains unexpected characters like `[0m[37;1m` or `[0m>` or `[K>` or even `>` (there is an `ESC` character before all of these but stackoverflow does not seem to let it be displayed). This is unexpected cause I don't seem to see any of these characters from the mintty program.

Why is this happening? Where are these characters coming from? How can I prevent them from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected characters are escape sequences used to format text output (concerning the terminal emulator). (See [Wikipedia: terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) for more about this.)

In detail, the output of prompt may be configured using certain bash variables, namely [PS1, PS2, PS3, PS4](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command). In [How to change bash prompt color based on exit code of last command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015463/how-to-change-bash-prompt-color-based-on-exit-code-of-last-command/43015676#43015676), the effect of modifying them (just for fun) is shown.

In your case, the call of `bash` should source a special script which re-defines them simply without any escape sequence. Thus, you could get rid of the undesired formatting. This may help: [SO: Running a custom profile file on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040872/running-a-custom-profile-file-on-remote-host) but this seems also promising: [Is it possible to start a bash shell with a profile at a custom location, in a one liner command?](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3jilax/is_it_possible_to_start_a_bash_shell_with_a/).

Writing this, I remembered that certain commands (e.g. `ls`) support colored output also. As I was not sure I tried this:

```
$ mkdir test ; cd test ; touch test1 ; ln -s test1 test2 ; mkdir test3 ; touch test4 ; chmod a+x test4

$ ls --color
test1  test2  test3  test4

$
```

I do not know how to format it with colors here but, on my xterm, it's looking like Mardi Gras. Thus, I use `hexdump` to show the effect:

```
$ ls --color | hexdump -c
0000000   t   e   s   t   1  \n 033   [   0   m 033   [   0   1   ;   3
0000010   6   m   t   e   s   t   2 033   [   0   m  \n 033   [   0   1
0000020   ;   3   4   m   t   e   s   t   3 033   [   0   m  \n 033   [
0000030   0   1   ;   3   2   m   t   e   s   t   4 033   [   0   m  \n
0000040
```

As you can see: `ls` does use terminal escape sequences also. Then I remembered the variable `TERM`. This link [The TERM variable](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-11.html) mentions the `terminfo` or `termcap` also which are probably part of the game.

Thus, in addition to the re-definition of `PS1` ... `PS4`, it could be useful to redefine `TERM` also:

```
$ TERM=

$ ls --color | hexdump -c
0000000   t   e   s   t   1  \n   t   e   s   t   2  \n   t   e   s   t
0000010   3  \n   t   e   s   t   4  \n                                
0000018

$
```

Btw. I recognized that the bash prompt is still colored. Thinking twice this becomes obvious: The escape sequences in `PS1` ... `PS4` are "hard-coded" i.e. does not consider the setting of `TERM`.

**Update:**

To test this I wrote a sample script `mybashrc`:

```
PS1="> "
PS2=">>"
PS3=
PS4="++ "
TERM=
```

and tested it with bash in cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ bash --init-file mybashrc -i
> echo "$PS1 $PS2 $PS3 $PS4"
> >>  ++ 
> exit
exit

$
```

Btw. I noticed that the [Backspace] key works somehow strange in my sample session: It still has the intended effect but the output is wrong. Output is  instead of deleting the last character although the internal buffer seems to handle this correctly:

```
$ bash --init-file mybashrc -i
> echo "Ha ello"
Hello
> echo "Ha ello" | hexdump -c
0000000   H   e   l   l   o  \n
0000006
> exit
exit

$
```

(In both cases, I typed [Backspace] once after `echo "Ha`.) The reason is possibly the missing terminal emulation.

Thus, I believe if the console (in your application) handles backspaces in the output channel of the bash appropriately then it should be less confusing.

Comment: Is there any command or argument or parameter to tell the `bash.exe` program to prevent it from adding those escape sequence and color codes completely?

Comment: I just read the `man bash`again concerning the effect of arguments `-i` and `--login` (and the others) because I had the idea that these could be related to your problem too. If I understood it right, these arguments define mainly what scripts are executed at start-up and exit of bash. This lets me believe that there is actually no color support built-in. Every formatting is done by configuration. Thus, the above hints should be sufficient.

Comment: Thus, the solution is probably to start your bash with (additional argument) `--init-file` or `--rcfile` and a script which re-defines the mentioned variables `PS1` ... `PS4` and `TERM`.